# how to create scheduled task

Tags: c++, winapi, scheduled-tasks

I'm trying to create a scheduled task to run an exe from a specific path every 5 hours.

I have looked at 
[Weekly Trigger Example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384042.aspx)
and [Boot Trigger Example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446817.aspx), but they successfully create the task only when my code runs with elevated permissions.

I want to create the task for the current user, not as administrator.

Any ideas?

Comment: Not going to happen. You need admin rights to create scheduled tasks.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan that is not entirely true. A non-admin user can create a non-boot task as long as it runs in the user's own account and does not require elevated permissions. Only an admin can create a boot task, or a task that runs with elevated permissions.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan also note: "*Tasks registered with the TASK_LOGON_PASSWORD or TASK_LOGON_S4U flag will only launch if the specified user has the Logon as Batch privilege enabled. Administrators and Backup Operators group users have this privilege enabled by default.*"